# How to segment a gaussian function to equal-volume parts

Tags: python, statistics, signal-processing, gaussian

I'm trying to split a gaussian shaped curve, to K equal-volume segments, with Python for signal-filtering purposes.

I'm seeking for pseudo-code, general idea or a library that performs it.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

For example in the image below: for K=6. volumes s1 = s2 = ... = s6:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine percentiles of the distribution. You can use for this `scipy.stats.norm` class and its `.ppf()` method.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 25
sigma = 4
splits = 8

# define the normal distribution and PDF
dist = sps.norm(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
x = np.linspace(dist.ppf(.001), dist.ppf(.999))
y = dist.pdf(x)

# calculate PPFs
step = 1 / splits
quantiles = np.arange(step, 1.0 - step / 2, step)
ppfs = dist.ppf(quantiles)  # boundaries

# plot results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
ax.plot(x, y, color='k')
for i, ppf in enumerate(ppfs):
    ax.axvline(ppf, color=f'C{i}', label=f'{quantiles[i]:.3f}: {ppf:.1f}')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]
This is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66831140/4601890)